# How can I reduce the intensity of metallic/specular/roughness materials?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I have 3d models from an external source that have *metallic*, *specular*, and *roughness* maps included.  I've applied them all, and here's what I get:

[image]

They're applied properly, but the metal textures are far too shiny.  When I've got textures plugged into those specific nodes, however, I don't see any other controls available.  I'd like to turn down settings on one or more of those nodes to make those parts of the mesh still shiny, but maybe not QUITE so shiny.  How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure they are applied "properly" if they are "far too shiny"? And what nodes are you talking about? Not enough informations...

Comment: When I wrote "properly," I meant that they were accomplishing their main purpose, which was to distinguish between the metal/shiny parts and the non-metal/non-shiny parts.  Turning down the Fac on each of those nodes solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a *Vector > ColorRamp* after the *Image Textur*e and play with the needles, move them to increase the contrast or make them brighter/arker:

[image]

Or simply instead put a *Color > Brightness/Contrast*, or a *Converter > Math* in *Multiply* mode, etc...

Comment: Note that adding nodes to correct the color will work only in Blender, it won't be exported correctly. If you need to export, consider doing the color correction in the target software or editing the textures directly.

Comment: @L0Lock he didn't talk about exporting?

Comment: Yes, but considering his previous questions about exporting textures, I guess that's the end goal here. And it doesn't hurt mentioning it for other users in that scenario ;)

Comment: Sure, he should precise that

Comment: Instead of using a Color Ramp, I simply turned down the Fac on the metallic and roughness nodes from 1.00 to 0.75.  That gave me the effect I was wanting.  And @L0Lock, you're exactly right, I was looking for a way to export this as an FBX for use outside Blender.